# Is there a OOP snippets package for atom?

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, laravel-5

I'm looking for OOP snippets for atom but the laravel snippets that I downloaded by Cronos78 doesn't have a snippets like when I want to have `public function(){}` and other OOP syntax